# JavaScript Tally multiple elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, count

I have been tasked with a counting challenge which I should return an object containing a count of elements in the array. for e.g.

```
expect(createTally(['a', 'b', 'a'])).to.eql({ a: 2, b: 1 });
```

So I have managed to do this with the higher-order function reduce but I want to be able to do this with a for loop so I can really see how this works, my code for the reduce method is below...

```
const createTally = items => {
  const counter = items.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = (acc[curr] || 0) + 1
    return acc
  }, {})
  return counter
}
```

So far for my for loop I have ...

```
const createTally = items => {
  const tally = {};
  let count = 0

  if (items.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (items[i].length > count) {
        count += count + 1
        console.log(count)
      }

      const key = items[i]
      tally[key] = count
      return tally
    }

  } else {
    return tally;
  }
}
```

I am struggling to increment my count and not passing any tests other than being able to return an empty object when passed an empty array and passing 1 key value pair when given a single element, any help would be much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler solution would yield something like the following, without all those for loops:

```js
const createTally = (items = []) => {  
  const tally = {}

  items.forEach(key => {
    tally[key] = tally[key] ? tally[key] + 1 : 1
  })

  return tally
}

console.log(createTally(['a', 'b', 'a']))
```

Comment: The `if` condition is not unnecessary. Code will work even without it. `tally[key] = tally[key] ? tally[key] + 1 : 1` can be written as `tally[key] = (tally[key] || 0) + 1`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure why you are checking the `.length` of the item in your for-loop implementation. The main thing you need to do is iterate over your array of items using a `for` loop. Then check if the current item is in your `tally` object. If it already is you can increment its associated counter value, if it isn't, you can initialize its associated counter value to 1.

The `for` loop won't iterate if your array length is initially 0 (ie: empty), so it will your code by default will return an empty object if this is the case.

See example below (see code comments for further details):

```js
const createTally = items => {
  const tally = {}; // acts as the `acc`

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { // loop over indexes in your array
    let current = items[i]; // get current item in your array (curr)
    
    // if statement peforms this logic seen in `.reduce()`: acc[curr] = (acc[curr] || 0) + 1
    if(tally[current]) // if the current item is already a key in your object then...
      tally[current]++ // increment the counter for current item
    else // if the current item isn't an item in your object, then...
      tally[current] = 1; // initialize the counter to 1
  }
  return tally; // return the `tally` (modified by the for loop)
}

console.log(createTally(['a', 'b', 'a'])); // {"a": 2, "b": 1}
console.log(createTally([])); // {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created my unnecessary loops and condition. You just need a single loop and an if condition.

Run a loop. Check if the item is already inside the object. If it is there increase it by one. Otherwise assign it to `0` and then it will be increase by `1`.

You also don't need to check the length of the array in the start. Consider if the `length` is `0` the for loop will not iterate even once and `tally` will be an empty object returned at end.

```js
const createTally = items => {
   const tally = {};
   for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (!tally[items[i]]) {
         tally[items[i]] = 0;
      }
      tally[items[i]]++;
   }
   return tally
}


console.log(createTally(['a', 'b', 'a']))
```